# Are the vector expressions $\vec{x}^TA\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}^TA \vec{x}$ equivalent?

Tags: vectors

Are these vector expressions equal?
$$\vec{x}^TA\vec{r} \qquad\vec{r}^TA \vec{x}$$

Can I combine them?

A is symmetric.

Comment: Wherte have you encoutered these expressions? And _exactly what_ are $\vec x, \vec r$ and $A$?

Comment: Agreed, you should tell us what these quantities are. What is $A$ for example? You've written this symbol without defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric, then the relationship holds, since $(x^TAr)^T=r^TA^Tx=r^TAx$, and since the result is a scalar, equality holds (all scalars are symmetric).  If $A$ is not symmetric, it is easy to come up with counterexamples.